# HTML 5 drag and drop to exact position

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I want my element that I am dragging to drop into exactly the position it was released. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. So far I'm get the drop coordinates in the drop event and then setting the top and left properties. It works, sort of, except I have to offset the left and top which makes me suspect there is something not right. Here is my function. Can anyone point me in the right direction

```
var dropped = function (e) {
    cancel(e);

    machine.parentNode.removeChild(machine);
    e.target.appendChild(machine);

    $(machine).css("top", (e.offsetY - 40) + 'px');
    $(machine).css("left", (e.offsetX - 30) + 'px');
    $("#text").html(e.offsetX + ' - ' + e.offsetY);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're already using jquery, the easiest method is probably to use the jQueryUI draggable interaction

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Thanks for that. If it were a commercial project I would use JqueryUI or Telerik. However I'm doing this as a bit of side project to learn the newer HTML/HTML 5 features so I'd like to understand the best practice for coding it myself. Cheers, Chris.